# ejs Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, view, ejs

i m learning ejs and ran into this error while trying to send get response into a view and get the tag responce on browser like h1>its a<%=kindOfDay%> ! not showing result in header form it just gives the string responce with an error
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

heres my code express

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyparser = require("body-parser")
const { send } = require('process')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
app.set("view engine", "ejs")

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let today = new Date()
    let day = "";
    if (today.getDay() === 6 || 0) {
        day = "weekend"
    } else {
        res.send("work day")
    }
    res.render("list", { kindOfDay: day })
        //res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

here is the view code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>to do list</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>its a
        <%=kindOfDay%> !</h1>
    <p>its a
        <%=kindOfDay%> !</p>
</body>

</html>
```

this is the error message i keep getting

```
Example app listening at http://localhost:3000
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\zahab\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\zahab\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at done (C:\Users\zahab\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1035:10)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\zahab\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:280:5)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\zahab\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\zahab\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\zahab\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\zahab\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\zahab\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (C:\Users\zahab\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:624:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\zahab\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:149:14)
    at done (C:\Users\zahab\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1035:10)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\zahab\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:280:5)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\zahab\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\zahab\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\zahab\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error because I forgot to add a `return` statement. So you might want to double-check that **where applicable**:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let today = new Date()
    let day = "";
    if (today.getDay() === 6 || 0) {
        day = "weekend"
    } else {
        return res.send("work day")   // add a return statement
    }
    return res.render("list", { kindOfDay: day })   // add a return statement
        //res.send('Hello World!')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this part, you already sent a res.send("work day") and after outside the "else" again you are trying to send a new element res.render("list", { kindOfDay: day }), that's the problem 'Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client', because you already sent and trying a new. If you comment this part and run will work. So, you need to change your logical programming in this specific part. Your callback function in your endpoint '/' needs to return just one context as a response.

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyparser = require("body-parser")
const { send } = require('process')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const path = require('path')

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set("view engine", "ejs")

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let today = new Date()
    let day = "";
    if (today.getDay() === 6 || 0) {
        day = "weekend"
    } else {
        res.status(200).send("work day")
    }
    //res.render("list", { kindOfDay: day })
        //res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```